# Keep cross validation prediction and fold assignment for h2o.automl

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o

I don't see an option to set the arguments

`keep_cross_validation_predictions`

and

`keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment`

for `h2o.automl()` in h2o R package.

Is there another way to access cross validation dataset used in `h2o.automl()` call?

The reason for this need is that the response variable used in the model is log-transformed, and cross validation error calculated may be misleading. If we have access to cross validation dataset, then we'll be able to know which observations were used, and then used the un-transformed response to compare against predicted values from the model used in a particular fold.

Comment: see argument `fold_column` to provide custom grouping (fold assignment). Having folds assigned manually with `fold_column` would allow to track cv dataset across complete AutoML pipeline and run necessary comparisons. http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_column.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can know set these parameters to `TRUE` in the latest version of AutoML. Please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.automl.html) on `h2o.automl()` parameters for more details.